# PHP Soapclient in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soap-client

I want to use php's built in [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapclient.php) class in laravel 5

I tried using it directly is shows error saying

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SoapClient' not found.

I tried adding `SoapClient` in aliases array in `config/app.php` like this

```
'SoapClient' => SoapClient::class
```

Still not working

what should I do?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Did you try importing it at the top? That is, `use SoapClient;`

Comment: It worked after adding use SoapClient, please post as answer I will accept it @JoelHinz

Comment: Try https://github.com/ACFBentveld/Soap. It uses laravel elequent methods like $soap->table

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The class needs to be imported, so either do that at the top:

`use SoapClient;`

or reference it directly later:

`$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);`

Comment: where to find the documentation for above, what is options ?

Comment: here you go: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php @151291

Answer (score 2):

I faced with same problem.

I activated Soap extension **after** I use `php artisan serve` command and although I restarted my apache server I received same error..

After too many tries I stop artisan and restart it again and that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have libxml and soap extensions installed for it to load the SoapClient class.

So check `php -i | grep limxml` and `php -i | grep soap`to see if they are installed.

For php 7.2 this would be needed to apt install and restart php/server.

```
apt-get install libxml php7.2-soap
```

Then check your php ini again. ubuntu ini path for the conf

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini

extension=soap.so
```

After that you should be able to run new object command.

Comment: There was no issue with the extension, still thanks for your help

Comment: @Akshay Khale issue is likely then that you called class without \ as in root namespace so new \SoapClient otherwise it will use namespace of controller you are writing in.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I have accepted the right answer.